# install FreeBSD 11 in my hd stop in 99%

Tags: usb, freebsd, dual-boot

i'm new in using freebsd 11 but really want to make it my primary system with arch.

i read a lot in freebsd forums and handbook i'm glad to do that.

i begin installing it in virtualbox and take a time until i realised I'm ready to do it in my hard like a primary partition with other distro of linux.

Today i downloaded

> FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64-mini-memstick.img

and in arch made it in usb by

> dd if=FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64-mini-memstick.img bs=1M of=/dev/sdb

I started to install it until reached to the install base.txz package and it stoped in 99%

I changed the mirror and repeated all the process with the same result it stoped in 99% of install base.txz.

What i can do?

Comment: Please take some time to write questions. Have you waited enough time? I had better results using current, give 11.1 RC a try.

Comment: Did you check the checksum? Did you see any error message?

Comment: in real i want to install freebsd but i wasn't able to do that so i started with TrueOS and dosn't like it  had a lot of problems that made  me hate it

Comment: The hash dosn't  match so i download another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in hash of iso.
i check it by

> $ md5sum FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64-mini-memstick.img
>   it dosn't match with the hash of my downloaded file.